# Summation of Prime Numbers in C++

Tags: c++, primes

Hi guys I am working on a program to give the sum of all prime numbers under two million. Here's what I have... and I know this method works for finding prime numbers because I have used it before... however when I run this program I keep getting an infinite loop and no output.... any help would be greatly appreciated!

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    bool isPrime=true;
    int i = 2;
    int sum = 0;
    do{

        for ( int j = 2; j < i; j++)
        {
            if ( i % j == 0 )
            {
                isPrime=false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime)
        {
            cout << "Prime: " << i << endl;
            sum += i; // add prime number to sum
        }
        i++;

    }while(i < 2000000);

    cout << "the sum of all the primes below two million is: " << sum << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's looping forever, and not just taking along time?

Comment: Asking other people to spot errors in your code is not productive.  You should use the debugger to figure out where things are going wrong.

Comment: The reason you think it's in an infinite loop is probably that it never writes any output (which is just because you never set `isPrime` as true.

Comment: Your program not contains news. I recommend doing a separate function to test numbers and another to add them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only logical error I can find is that you never re-set `isPrime` to `true` inside the loop, but that shouldn't cause an infinite loop, just wrong results.

I doubt it goes in an infinite loop though, I just think it takes a long time because it's sub-optimal. You don't need to check every number until `i`, `sqrt(i)` or even `i/2` would do it.

Even better, you can generate a sieve of primes (google this) and then just add them up - this will be wildly more efficient.

Comment: +1: Also worth mentioning if the OP decides to keep the iterative loop to throw another half of the factors out by starting at 3 and incrementing by +2 through each iteration (and remembering to start the summation @ 3 (1+2)). No sense in testing even numbers (though I would still just make a sieve and then do the summation as you have suggested).

Comment: @WhozCraig ah yes, another good optimization - but I'd still use the sieve. If the range is known, a sieve is always better.

Comment: Absolutely. If the top-side limit is known, a sieve is *the* answer.

Comment: awesome thanks for mentioning the sieve.... im still new to optimization and kinda stumbling through learning it but this totally helps! thx!

Comment: @WhozCraig of course, your idea to skip numbers *is* a sieve itself, no? :P

Comment: @SunHypnotic as a fun fact, can you post results here (sieve solution vs non-sieve). I'm actually curious how much faster it is. :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore lol. I hardly consider sieving out just one of the multiple sets (2-factors) a real sieve, which filters *every* multiple of every discovered prime up to the top-side limit.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore will do! taking a look into right now.... the current solution is still running after ~15 min with no answer....working on implementing the sieve solution now

Comment: Before you started the test, did you fix the code by setting isPrime to true inside the do {} loop?

Comment: FWIW, you don't even need sqrt(i) every time. You only need an integer approximation of sqrt. You can generate successive perfect squares by adding successive odd numbers, and continue using the same limit until you reach the next perfect square (e.g., sqrt(16) = 4, so your limit is 5 for all numbers from 16 to 25, then 6 for all numbers from 26 to 36, 7 for all numbers from 37 to 49, etc.)

Comment: @SunHypnotic Very brute sieve-usage [example written in C++0x](http://ideone.com/WDvvFJ) if you're curious. Could be made considerably more efficient but you may be surprised how quickly it finds your sum.

Comment: @WhozCraig here's one that does it at compile-time http://ideone.com/JcB3DQ (limited by template recursion depth & can be optimized a lot) :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Lol.. You're poor stack. Unfortunately my expansion is  limited to 512. Is that a Clang thing, btw? (I'm running on an Apple using LLVM 4.1, which I believe uses a pretty-well maintained clang.)

Comment: @WhozCraig ideone uses gcc & is limited at 500 (at least the version on the site). Fun experiment though.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you have an infinite loop.  You forget to set `isPrime` to `true`, as Luchian Grigore noted, but your code will also take an awfully long time to run.  Notice that you can stop doing trial division once `j*j > i`.

Comment: I'd advice against `j*j > i` - it requires a multiplication on every iteration, whereas `sqrt(i)` would be called only once.

Comment: Since 'i' increments, the sqrt(i) grows steadily also.  Adding an isqrt variable and updating it near i++ by using if( isqrt * isqrt < i ) isqrt++ is better.

Answer (score 0):

If you are also concerned about making things more efficient with minimum effort -- to get the primes you only need to check numbers of the form (6n + 1) and (6n + 5)

So including something like in your main loop :

```
int p6 = p % 6;
if (p6 == 1) {
    result = isPrime(p);
    p += 4;
} else if (p6 == 5) {
    result = isPrime(p):
    p += 2;
}
```

Will speed you up by a multiple. Don't forget the corner cases 2 and 3 though.